# Make a histogram for a pandas dataframe where the columns are the individual bins

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, visualization, graph-visualization

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

| Blue | Green | Red |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 27.0 | 30.0 |
| 24.0 | 3.0 | 22.0 |
| 3.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 |
| 5.0 | 0.0 | 5.0 |
| 2.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 |
| 10.0 | 20.0 | 7.0 |

I want to make a histogram with each of the column names in as the bins on the x-axis, and the summed values of the numbers as the bar heights. How can I do this, as most of the visualization library examples I've seen have not used the columns themselves as the bins. Any visualization library is fine.

Comment: This sounds more like a basic bar graph than a histogram. If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want "Blue", 'Green", and "Red" on the x-axis with bars of height 43, 58, and 72, repectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you need a generic bar chart which can be created like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Blue': [1, 2, 3], 'Green': [2, 3, 4], 'Red': [3, 4, 5]})

# Calculate the sum of each column
column_sums = df.sum()

# Plot the bar chart
column_sums.plot(kind='bar', color=['blue', 'green', 'red'])
plt.show()
```

[image]